# Edit multiple HTML text inputs simultanously

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-input

I have 2 HTML (form elements) inputs, both of type text. When I write in the first one, I want the same text I write to appear in the second text input as I write. Is this possible? How? This is surprisingly hard finding on the web.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to hook into input events on the first `input` and set that as the value of the second.

Comment: Add a change event handler to the first input. In this update the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('first').onkeyup = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('second').value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Type in this">
<input type="text" id="second">
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I am working with Angular 2 so I found a better/simpler solution in their docs, but I asked for general HTML so your answer is more appropriate and will help others more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="inputFirst" onchange="mutipleText()">
<input type="text" id="inputSecond" >   

 function mutipleText(){
    var firstInput = $('#inputFirst').val();
    $('#inputSecond').val(firstInput)
    }
```