# How to insert a value into multiple selected inputs simultaneously?

Tags: angular

I have a html table containing input tags and I want a mechanism to allow me to insert the same value into multiple table cells at the same time without having to manually type it in every cell.

for example a table like this :

```
id | attr1 | attr2 | attr3
1     "x"    "x"      "x"
2     "x"    "z"      "y"
3     "a"    "w"      "x"
```

x is the value i want to insert into those specific cells, i don't want to manually type it.

EDIT : this is how my table looks like :

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
    
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <input type"text" value="{{element.position}}"></td>
  </ng-container>
    
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <input type"text" value="{{element.name}}"> </td>
  </ng-container>
    
  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <input type"text" value="{{element.weight}}"> </td>
  </ng-container>
    
  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <input type"text" value="{{element.symbol}}"> </td>
  </ng-container>
    
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

```js
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
    
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
    
/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to convert a text to an html table in a code editor?

Comment: @Shahriar i have a table containing input tags in its table cells.
instead of typing the values manually for every input, i want a mechanism to select multiple inputs ( cells ) and type the text and that text is shared among all the selected cells.
It's the exact mechanism present in Microsoft EXCEL that i want to achieve

Comment: Got it, so please add the HTML code and provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: This helps solving your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950192/edit-multiple-html-text-inputs-simultanously

Comment: Some help to get you started: First you want to create an array. Then use 'fromEvent()' to listen for holding a key, you might want it to clear the array on keydown. Then you want a second observable, taking the cells that are clicked. Then you combine those observables and store something that identifies the cells you selected in the array. You can render some css using ngClass if a cell is in the array. And then you want each input to have a onchanges event bound to a function that also sets all the other inputs that have their identifier in the array. I'll gladly help if you get stuck.

Comment: @Shahriar check my edit post. although your solution works, it's not what i precisely need. I need a mechanism to select multiple cells by holding down the shift key and then insert the  new value into that set of cells

Comment: Give the logic a try, step by step. We will help you out if you can't get there on your own. I gave you plenty of things to google. A single line of .js isn't gonna fix your problem, but there is a lot to learn from what you are trying to do. So, give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step by Step Guide

I hope you managed to find out some things on your own by now, but I decided I wanted to give it a try too. So here is a step by step guide for you on how I managed to get there.

#### Step 1

First create an array to hold the selected fields.

```js
selected: string[] = [];
```

#### Step 2

Then use 'fromEvent()' to listen for holding a key, you might want it to clear the array on keydown. In this case you might want to listen to both keyup and keydown events.

```js
keyDowns$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
keyUps$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');

ctrlPresses$ = merge(this.keyDowns$, this.keyUps$).pipe(
  filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === CTRL), // <-- Keycode for CTRL = 17
  debounceTime(100),
  tap((x: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (x.type === 'keydown') {
      this.selected = [];
      this.ctrlPressed = true;
      console.log('CTRL is down');
    }
  }),
  tap((x: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (x.type === 'keyup') {
      this.ctrlPressed = false;
      console.log('CTRL is up');
    }
  })
);
```

#### Step 3

Then create a second observable, taking the cells that are clicked. Now combine those observables and store something that identifies the cells you selected in the array. To keep it simple I just flipped a boolean in the first observable, but you actually want to avoid side-effects like that using higher-order observables. The second observable we get from pushing click events to our own subject.

```js
selectionSubject = new Subject();

get selection$() {
  return this.selectionSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    tap((x: string) => {
      if (this.ctrlPressed && this.selected.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        this.selected.push(x);
      }
    })
  );
}

onClicked(event: MouseEvent) {
  const target = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
  this.selectionSubject.next(target.id);
}
```

#### Step 4

Render some css using ngClass if a cell is in the array.

```js
isSelected(id: string) {
  if (this.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
    return 'selected';
  }
}
```

Add some basic styling:

```css
input {
  margin: 2px;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

.selected {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt cornflowerblue;
}
```

#### Step 5

Bind a change event for each input to a function that also sets all the other inputs that have their identifier in the array. Binding the keyup event worked best for me.

```js
onChange(e) {
  this.selected.forEach((id) => {
    this[id].nativeElement.value = e;
  });
}
```

#### Finally

The inputs in html should look something like this:

```html
<input
  #tf1
  [ngClass]="isSelected('tf1')"
  id="tf1"
  (click)="onClicked($event)"
  (keyup)="onChange($event.target['value'])"
  type="text"
/>
```

Here is the example code in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q5dgb5?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

The code can probably still be optimized a little. I also added clearing of the selection on mouse clicks, and some styling magic to be able to have multiple (fake) carets in the Stackblitz project.
It clutters the basic logic a little, so I didn't include it here.

Comment: man I just can't seem to make it work and i'm starting to panick because I need to have this working soon...
your code is triggering a typpescript error and my table is way more complex than that and now I'm panicking

Comment: Always stay calm, there's always a way to please typescript. What does the error say? Or even better can you reproduce it in a simple project. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I also made the carets blink in sync on the Stackblitz btw, that was bothering me. XD If you can manage to get me some code, I can look into it right away if you want, I'm done working for today.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i managed to make it work after a very slow, step by step debugging and I couldn't have done it without your help.